# bigcartel : Customizing a contact page

Tags: bigcartel

I am having trouble setting up a custom page on my bigcartel.

I want to set up a custom sort of contact page that people can put info into and send it to me, its sort of a giveaway entry form.

I figured I could just rip the html code off of the contact page and edit it but after doing so I ran into multiple problems.

- Captcha is not working on the custom page i've set up, but it works fine in the preview on big cartel.
- If I enter in all the info it will return to the contact page instead of returning to the custom page I set up.

Is there anyway achieve what I'm trying to do solely on bigcartel?

Answer (score 1):

There's not currently a way to customize the Big Cartel contact form beyond basic CSS styles -- moving it to a custom page instead of "/contact" will cause issues, and there's validation in the system to only allow for the built-in fields to come through. This means that it's not possible to add or remove any additional form fields.

You're better off integrating a custom form solution like Google Docs or Wufoo, and then replacing the contents of the Contact page entirely with the third-party form code.